# How to filter posts in categories in PHP Laravel

Tags: php

posts: id, title, ...

categories: id, category_name, ...

category_post: post_id, category_id

categories :

```
Categogy 1
Category 2
```

posts :

```
Post 1
Post 2
```

category_post :

```
post_id | category_id
Post 1  | Category 1
Post 2  | Category 1
Post 1  | Category 2
```

Now. I want filter posts which have in both Category 1 and Category 2.

Result : Post 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$recruitmentId = [3,4,5];
        $model = Recruitment::with('categories')
            ->selectRaw("recruitments.id, recruitments.title, category_recruitment.recruitment_id")
            ->join('category_recruitment',function($join){
                $join->on("category_recruitment.recruitment_id","=","recruitments.id");
            })
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
        $collection = collect($model);
        $data = $collection->filter(function ($item, $key) use ($recruitmentId){
            if (!empty($item['categories']) && count($item['categories']) >= count($recruitmentId)) {
                $query = null;
                foreach ($item['categories'] as $k => $v) {
                    foreach ($recruitmentId as $key => $value) {
                        $query .= $v['category_id'] == $value;
                    }
                }
                return $query;
            }
        })
        ->unique('title')
        ->values()
        ->all();
        dd($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is many to many relationships 
u can $this->belongsTomany method alos  append method use as filter in laravel ..
[laravel many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)